# Nginx-Clojure jvm may be mad for wrong options

Tags: java, nginx, server, proxy

I'm trying to set up a proxy server because I want to use body filters to modify google search result content. I copied the result of building the Java code to `/jars` in the installed nginx-clojure folder and set it as follows. However, when I add this part of body_filter_name, the server does not start with an error.

> 2023/05/17 16:31:09 [error] 91280#0: jvm may be mad for wrong options!
> See hs_err_pid****.log for detail! restarted 15 2023/05/17 16:31:09
> [alert] 34461#0: worker process 91280 exited with fatal code 2 and
> cannot be respawned

I'm trying to find the log file, but I can't see it

```
sudo find / -name "hs_err_pid*.log"
```

I will be very grateful if you tell me how to solve the problem

```java
package org.example.replacer;

import nginx.clojure.java.ArrayMap;
import nginx.clojure.java.StringFacedJavaBodyFilter;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;

public class GoogleLogoReplacer extends StringFacedJavaBodyFilter {
    @Override
    protected Object[] doFilter(Map<String, Object> request, String body, boolean isResponse) throws IOException {
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(body);
        Element logo = doc.select("img.jfN4p").first();
        if (logo != null) {
            logo.attr("src", "http://via.placeholder.com/400");
        }
        return new Object[] {200, new ArrayMap<>(new Object[]{"Content-Type", "text/html"}), doc.toString()};
    }
}
```

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    jvm_path auto;
    jvm_classpath "libs/*:jars/*:jars/logo-replacer-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar";

    jvm_options "-Xms1024m";
    jvm_options "-Xmx1024m";

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            proxy_pass https://www.google.com;
        }

        location /search {
            proxy_pass https://www.google.com/search;
            body_filter_type java;
            body_filter_name org.example.replacer.GoogleLogoReplacer;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }

}
```